# Context switches pr second ( How many can a server handle )

Tags: hardware

In my case im thinking about Citrix servers handling clients, but i was wondering if there is a way to estimate this?

I understand that there is no way to get this accurate without actualy trail and error, but i was hoping for a rough estimate. In this case the server will log warrnings / errors if the box goes above X context switches and i need to figure out ok numbers to start the trail and error on. Since it seems much of the monitoring software uses context switches to detect to high load, it would be nice with some sort of generic method to calculate a rough number of what the server can handle.

This is on windows servers if that mathers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938606.aspx. This is as near as you'll come to a firm value for X.

Note however that excessive context switches are only likely to be a problem if you're getting excessive hardware interrupts. As long as interrupts aren't pre-empting other threads Windows should be perfectly capable of handling many concurrent threads even if it's a heavily loaded terminal server.

JR